# Converting 'integer strings' to integer array

Tags: c, arrays, atoi

I'm trying to pass in an array of integers into my program. Is there a better way to convert it to integers? I'm currently getting an error: "Variable sized object may not be initialized"

```
for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    int arr[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `argc` and `argv` are the arguments passed to main, it is unlikely that `argv[0]` is something that you want to convert into an integer. `argv[0]` usually contains the name of the program.

Your code snippet is declaring an array local to the loop body. What you likely want is an array defined outside the loop body, and you want to assign to individual array elements within the loop body.

```
int arr[argc];
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    arr[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: I forgot about the first argument being the name of the program. Solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**You are declaring your array `arr` every time you loop**.

change your loop like  this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int arr[argc];
    int i=0;


    for(i = 0; i < argc-1; i++)
    {
       arr[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
       printf("arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Sukhvir@Sukhvir-PC ~
$ gcc -Werror -Wall -g -o test test.c

Sukhvir@Sukhvir-PC ~
$ ./test 3 4 5
arr[0] = 3
arr[1] = 4
arr[2] = 5
```