# In C, how do I convert a string contaning numbers to an int array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

In my C program I get an input like this:
1,2,5,13,18
how can i turn this string to actual numbers?
I tried `strtok()` but it gave me segmentation fault and i have no idea why, maybe you can help me on that on the side?

Comment: Hi Tom! What language are you programming in?

Comment: I'm using C with ansi 90

Comment: Could you share the code you are trying at the moment? I think in that case `strtok` and `atoi` would get the job done for you

Comment: Please post your code and what you have done so far.

Comment: Thank you all, i found the solution to the problem and i appreciate all the help, thanks again :D

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to see your code but this might suffice:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int arr[argc];
int i;

for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
   arr[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Credit goes to >>> Check this out for more info: [Converting 'integer strings' to integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473439/converting-integer-strings-to-integer-array)

Answer (score 1):

You have not given your code here, may be you are not using `strtok()` in a proper way. Please refer to the documentation and see the examples in that page to know more about the use of `strtok()`.

Use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok) to tokenize the string and then [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi) to convert the string to a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "1,2,5,13,18";
    char* pch;
    pch = strtok(str, ",");
    while(pch)
    {
        int x = atoi(pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, ",");
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```